# inserting an "a" at the end of a transaction number in different places in a line?

Tags: python, pandas, split

I am trying "add" an 'a' at the end of every transaction number. I want to add characters to the string dependent on the starting characters of the column.
An example of the data:
every line starting in RH has 6 '~' untill the TXN number
every line starting in RL has 7 '~'
every line starting in RA has 6 '~'

RH~11123~~~~~txn123~120~~~~~~~ball

RL~111~~~~~~txn125~12~~~~~hat

RA~111asf~~~~~~~txn149~13~~~~~~~~~car

So I want to look like this with an addition of an 'a' after transaction number:

RH~11123~~~~~txn123a~120~~~~~~~ball

RL~111~~~~~~txn125a~12~~~~~hat

RA~111asf~~~~~~~txn149a~13~~~~~~~~~car

I have attempted to use str split, but it doesn't seem to actually be splitting the string up properly.  I am stuck trying to get only each line starting with a certain character.

```
(np.where(~df['1'].str.startswith('RH'),
                  df['1'].str.split('~').str[6],
                  df['1']))
```

Comment: "RA has 6 '~'" - RA has 8 `~` char before `txn`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of spitting by `~` use regex substitution:

```
In [463]: df.col.str.replace(r'(txn\d+)', r'\1a', regex=True)
Out[463]: 
0       RH~11123~~~~~txn123a~120~~~~~~~ball
1            RL~111~~~~~~txn125a~12~~~~~hat
2    RA~111asf~~~~~~~txn149a~13~~~~~~~~~car
Name: col, dtype: object
```

(`col` is your column name, replace with your actual one)